# Parfor in Matlab will not terminate in different occasions but For does

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I am running into a strange issue with 'parfor' in Matlab. Most of the time the code runs fine. But in some other cases when the input changes, Parfor seems 'dead'. It just doesn't terminate even when I wait for 1 full day - changing it to For will take just 1 hour (normally if Parfor works then it takes about 20 minutes).

There's no error code. I can't get inside parfor to debug. What might possibly going on?

I don't have any nested For inside this Parfor. There is no slicing of the indices. Though I do call some simple mex functions compiled from C.

Comment: Is this a local pool? If it's not, switching to a local pool would be the first thing to try to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The only solution I know is "printf debugging". Try logging as much as you can to log files. It may give you some hint.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that reproduces this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think I have a rough answer to this.

The answer is in the mex functions compiled from C that were called inside the Parfor. Those functions are not very well written, with many global pointers. I think with Parfor and having 8 workers, having to divide the memory, something messed up the mex files. It doesn't happen as often with For, but I found out that sometimes it does.

The reason why the code was all hung up is because there was a line that says: if something is NaN, then pause. Pause should not be in a parfor because the multiple workers won't know what to do with it. Hence I thought the parfor loop was acting like an infinite loop.

Note below: demand_full is a mex file and when I change the 'pause' to 'print circ' it's all NaN when the error happens.

```
for j = 1:NDRAWS
pmat_temp = 1:mkt;
parfor i = 1:mkt
    tauvec = [zeros(1, numD(i)) ones(1, numR(i))];
    [circ] = demand_full(prices{i}, tauvec, rhoarray(i, j), theta);
    y = log(mean_mat2D_c(circ(tauvec==1))) - log(mean_mat2D_c(circ(tauvec==0)));
    pR = exp(rho_param1 + rho_param2 * rhoarray(i, j))...
            / (1 + exp(rho_param1 + rho_param2 * rhoarray(i, j)));
    lambda = exp(n_param1 + n_param2 * log(hhld(i)) + n_param3 * rhoarray(i, j) + n_param4 * rhoarray(i, j)^2);
    pN = lambda^(length(tauvec)) / exp(lambda) / factorial_c(length(tauvec));
    p_market_config_temp = nchoosek_c(length(tauvec), numR(i)) * pR^numR(i) * (1 - pR)^numD(i);
    p_market_config = pN * (p_market_config_temp / (1 - pR^length(tauvec) - (1 - pR)^length(tauvec)));
    pmat_temp(i) = p_market_config * 1/sigma_q / sqrt(1/numR(i) + 1/numD(i)) * ...
        exp(-((yhat(i) - y) / sqrt(1/numR(i) + 1/numD(i)))^2 / 2 / sigma_q^2);
    if isnan(pmat_temp(i))
        pause
    end
end
pmat(:, j) = pmat_temp;
end
```